# Transition from one image to another

Tags: css

currently I'm using this code:

```
#div { background-image: url('imageurl.com'), url('imageurl2.com'); position: absolute !important; right: 0; left: 0; height: 210px !important; display: table-cell !important; vertical-align: middle !important;}

@keyframes FadeInOut {
 0% {
  opacity:1;
}
45% {
opacity:1;
}
55% {
opacity:0;
}
100% {
opacity:0;
}
}

#div img.top {
animation-name: FadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

I'm actually trying to implement the code from Demo 3 on this website: 
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

In that demo, there are two images in one div and the code is just fading the first one in and out on a timer. I tried implementing this myself using the above code, but it's fading anything in and out. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need implementation through background-image you can use pseudo-element:

```css
#cf2 {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-image: url("http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Windows%20Logo.jpg");
}

#cf2::after{
  content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url("http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Turtle.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

#cf2::after {
animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf2">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I tried using your code, but the image never fades out. It just stays there.

Comment: Oops! It works, but it has some trouble scaling. For example the div before would always stay within the browser window, but now it seems constrained to the left like it's supposed to, but extends far to the right when viewed on lower resolution windows. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @lolikols, I've changed code a little, now it must correctly work with any window size. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/SerafimGray/mLu5Lh80/1/)

Comment: Haha I was just opened up the page to say I figured it out. My fix was exactly the same as yours! Thank you! Marked as answer!

Answer (score 1):

here's the implementation, they use separate `<img>` tags to show/hide images: 
they are absolutely positioned one above the other, that one which is on top is just showing and hiding by the animation (which changes its opacity) - so the bottom one just becomes visible when top one has opacity = 0

```css
@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
#cf3 img.top {
  animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
#cf3 img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
#cf3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 281px;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf3" class="shadow">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Turtle.jpg">
  <img class="top" src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Windows%20Logo.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Ah shoot. Is there way for me to implement:

Comment: <div id="cf3" class="shadow">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Turtle.jpg">
  <img class="top" src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Windows%20Logo.jpg">
</div> using css?

Comment: @lolikols that means I'm using images directly from their website. they use 2 different img tags which are absolutely positioned one above the other, that one which is on top is just showing and hiding by the animation. I added explanation to the answer

Comment: Ah I see. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the HTML backend to add these image tags. Are tags like these something that I can implement using CSS?